# VBA Excel, Faster Copy Paste Formula code

Tags: excel, vba, performance, copy-paste, array-formulas

I need to copy formulas from the first row of an excel sheet template below for at least 5000 lines.

- Task 1 refresh formulas (I included 2 options and the first one seems slightly faster)
- Task 2 paste values refreshed
- Task 3 copy formats from the first row to the last one

I'm using the following code but its to slow. Is there a faster solution?
Please, could you help me?

Thanks a lot

```
 Sub Refresh_cs()

‘ CS_PASTE_AREA = “A10:QZ5000”

Application.ScreenUpdating = FALSE

Dim Arr             As Variant
If ActiveSheet.FilterMode = TRUE Then
    ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
End If

**'1a REFRESHING Option 1**

'REFRESHING Calculation Sheet
ActiveSheet.Outline.ShowLevels RowLevels:=4
ActiveSheet.Range("A9").EntireRow.Copy
Range("CS_PASTE_AREA").Select 
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlFormulas

**‘1b Refreshing Option 2**

Dim lastrow         As Long
Dim lastcol         As Long

' Find last CS Row
lastrow = Range("N3").Value - 1 - ActiveCell.Row
' Find last CS Column
ActiveSheet.Range("A9").Select
lastcol = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveCell.Row, Application.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
'Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(0, lastcol - 1)).Select

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Arr = Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(0, lastcol - 1))

Range("A10").Resize(lastrow, UBound(Arr, 2)).Formula = Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(0, lastcol - 1)).Formula
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

' 2 PASTE VALUES
Range("CS_PASTE_AREA").Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False  

' 3 PASTE FORMATS
ActiveSheet.Range("A10").EntireRow.Copy
Range("CS_PASTE_AREA").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlFormats
Application.CutCopyMode = FALSE

Range("CS_END") = "-"

'ActiveSheet.Outline.ShowLevels RowLevels:=1

Application.ScreenUpdating = TRUE

End Sub
```

Comment: 1) How big are these ranges?, 2) Which part is slow?, 3) How slow is it now and much faster does it need to be?

Comment: Wait, I see the range comment now .. So something like +2,000,000 cells?

Comment: Yes, approx. 2mln of cells. It's slow the copy paste formulas lines. Now the execution requires 90 seconds and I guess there i a more efficient way to perform the activity

Comment: why copy a formula and not do the calculation you need directly in vba?

Comment: The slowest part of copying and pasting is always the clipboard. If you can avoid using the windows clipboard then you can drastically speed up the code. Doing `Range1.Copy Destination:=Range2` avoids the clipboard. Also `Range1.Value = Range2.Value` would be fastest, but skips the formatting.

Comment: Doing a calculation directly in VBA is an option, but I should recode 500 long formulas and it's not immediate. I'm not an expert. Is there any on-line tool to speed-up the activity? Doing 'Range1.Value = Range2.Value', do you lost the formulas, don't you?

Comment: Are the source and target ranges the same size?  Or are you extending the source rows into the target range?

Comment: I need to extend the selection as source is one row and target are 4500 rows below